# How to enter multiple form input from Angular to python file

Tags: javascript, python, html, angular, typescript

I am working on an angular project, one module of this project requires me to take form inputs from the user using angular's frontend(html) and using these values as variables in a python file. The python file then interacts with an XML file, I have already done the XML portion. I just cant find a way to use those frontend inputs in the python file as variables.

Can you guys help me out with it or if anyone knows a resource or a webpage which can cater my problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have post the form back to your web application. Either by submitting it or (better for single page applications) via AJAX.

Comment: how can i post the object containing form inputs in the python file

Comment: Are the form inputs in 1 Object? then you can use JSON as an intermediate solution. In Angular convert the object to JSON and in Python convert the JSON to a dictionary.

Comment: Got it, Can i convert the dictionary in individual variables later on?

Comment: Also, Do i need a python framework for this? like django